# How to communicate one value between a program and a library (using mkfifo or so)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, pipe

I have a dynamical loaded library that calculates one special value. My Program needs to access this value (in C or C++).
I thought about named pipes. But they seem somehow strange for this purpose. If realised by a pipe, my library would write one value in a file and later, my program reads it. I read about a SIGPIPE signal. Why should I need one of those and do I have to use it?
I also read that in order to write in the named pipe, the pipe must be opened for reading. Where is the sense of that?
I planned to realize a named pipe by mkfifo. Somehow, in examples, I also see different calls, sometimes just a file is created and opened. Why can't I just do this? I really don't want to have any blocked pipes.

In the end, I just want to store one value such that it can be accessed by a library and by the program. Are there maybe other ways than pipes to realize this?

I don't think function return values are possible because all functions in the library are called internally and not from outside by my program (malloc hook).

Comment: Maybe function arguments and return values?

Comment: +1 to Nemo. Why didn't you make that comment an answer?

Comment: @R: Because it seemed too obvious...

Answer (score 2):

Even if your program is primarily a malloc hook (loading via LD_PRELOAD, I presume?) you can still access symbols from it. Define a function (say, `getMyValue()`) in the library, and in your main program, link `-ldl` and do something like:

```
void *vpGetMyValue = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "getMyValue");
if (!vpGetMyValue) {
  // Library not loaded! Do something else
}

int (*pGetMyValue)() = (int(*)())vpGetMyValue;
int myValue = pGetMyValue();
```

Comment: Only works for symbols exported by the library, of course.  But since questioner controls the library, should be fine...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What means exported symbols?

Comment: Exported symbols are variables or functions defined in a library that are visible to programs using that library. On Linux, by default, all non-static variables and functions are exported (note: on C++ you'll want to use `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling though).